# Is $$ deprecated in R Markdown LaTeX?

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, r-markdown

[I was reading here that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40492/what-are-the-differences-between-align-equation-and-displaymath) `$$` is deprecated in LaTeX and replaced with `\[` and `\]`. It seems the opposite when I use R Markdown in R Studio though.

If I wrap an equation in `$$` it will display block style, live preview, in my R Markdown (in R Studio). If I use `\[` and `\]` it will still knitr fine, but it won't showup R Studio live preview. See below.

[image]

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "March 2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\[x = R + F\]

$$x = R + E$$
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [linked Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40492/what-are-the-differences-between-align-equation-and-displaymath) is correct. `$$` is deprecated for LaTeX. However, you are not writing LaTeX but Rmarkdown, which is processed by `pandoc`. In the [pandoc manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#math) we find:

> TeX math will be printed in all output formats. How it is rendered depends on the output format:
>
> **LaTeX**
> It will appear verbatim surrounded by `\(...\)` (for inline math) or `\[...\]` (for display math).

So you can use `$$...$$` in Rmarkdown documents and still have the correct output when converting to PDF via LaTeX. The other form works due to another [pandoc extension](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-tex_math_single_backslash). If you need cross-references for equations, you should use [bookdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#equations), though.